# SQL interpolation bug in Ruby on Rails 3.2 tutorial chapter 11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

The author of the Ruby on Rails tutorial says he's happy to get reports of errors in the text, but then he immediately goes on to says he doesn't really expect there are any, so please don't report them to him directly.  Nevertheless, I believe I may have found such an error.  In code listing 11.44 of the 3.2 version of the tutorial the following method is defined:

```
  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = user.followed_user_ids.join(', ')
    where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", followed_user_ids, user)
  end
```

The first line of the method produces a string with the call to join().  The second line plugs that string into a placeholder inside the parentheses for the IN portion of the SQL WHERE clause.  I haven't tested this with the default SQLite driver, because I followed the author's instructions for the advanced exercises and switched to PostgreSQL for the test and development environments.  With the PostgreSQL driver, the placeholder replacement mechanism detects that the replacement variable for that placeholder is a string value and inserts the value with the surrounding single quote marks which SQL expects for string values.  So the resulting WHERE clause comes out as "`WHERE user_id IN ('...') OR ...`."  The user_id column is an INT column so this is rejected (at least with PostgreSQL).  The problem is eliminated later on in the text by a variant implementation of the method, using a subquery, but the author explicitly says that right after the failing code quoted above is added all of the validations in the test suite should pass.

If the author is monitoring this forum for bug reports on the tutorial, it would be nice to get a response acknowledging whether this is indeed a bug, and perhaps even have it corrected. :-)

Thanks!

[PS: The author instructs readers to report bugs here, using the tags "ruby-on-rails" and "tutorials" but SO does not allow the use of the "tutorials" tag.]

Comment: let me know if my solution worked for you and please tick it/vote up if it was useful. that *is* the point of SO.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this you could use:

```
  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = user.followed_user_ids
    where((['user_id = ?'] * followed_user_ids.size).join(' OR '), *followed_user_ids)
  end
```

This will construct a query with many `user_id = ? OR`s dependent on the size of the array and will pass in the int that postgreSQL should be happy to accommodate.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  However, as I noted in my OP, I'm not really looking for a workaround for the bug (the tutorial itself provides an even better approach using a subquery, which avoids the bug).  What I'm after is a way to let the author of the tutorial know that the bug is there so it can be fixed, and readers coming after me won't have to spend as much time as I did trying to figure out what was broken.

Comment: If it fixes the bug it solves your question and if it's a question on SO it has right and wrong answers and those answers get voted or chosen. Just saying this place isn't an SEO charity and the advice given to post here was done so for a reason. You lost my upvote on the good question for being anti-guidelines